# Changing select2 jquery plugin locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I have been trying to change the locale of `formatInputTooShort`.

In order to find the correct select2.js file (as I have several versions of the select2-rails gem) I inputed the command `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec gem list select2-rails`. Then I did `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec gem env` to find where the gem's are installed.

So I changed the correct (I think) select2.js file, restarted my unicorn server but the locale did not change on the minimumInputLength. It still says "Please enter 1 or more character" instead of my custom message.

Any clue what I might be doing wrong?

Note: I use english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the text by overriding the function by doing the following:

```
$(#my_selector).select2({
   minimumInputLength: 1, 
   formatInputLength: function(){
    return "Enter the text you want"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(#my_selector).select2({
   minimumInputLength: 1, 
  formatNoMatches: function () { return "No se encontraron resultados"; },
  formatInputTooShort: function (input, min) { 
    var n = min - input.length; return "Por favor, introduzca " + n + " nombre"; 
  },
  formatInputTooLong: function (input, max) { 
    var n = input.length - max; 
    return "Por favor, elimine " + n + " car" + (n == 1? "á" : "a") + "cter" + (n == 1? "" : "es"); 
  },
  formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) { 
    return "Sólo puede seleccionar " + limit + " elemento" + (limit == 1 ? "" : "s"); 
  },
  formatLoadMore: function (pageNumber) { 
    return "Cargando más resultados..."; 
  },
  formatSearching: function () { 
    return "Buscando..."; 
  }
});
```